# Setting a variable using a query that includes a different variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with a routine that manages several databases. Each DB has an activity log. I want to loop through the activity logs and get the latest activity date (formatted `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm`) for each DB.

If I hard code the database/table name into this statement, it works just fine.

```
SET @LatestLogDT = (SELECT FORMAT(MAX([ActivityDT]), N'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm') FROM MyDB.dbo.MyTable);
```

However, if I put this in a loop and try to insert the db/table name as a dynamic variable, it fails, saying I must declare the variable. I've whittled the code down as thin as possible to demonstrate the issue. In this example, I declare @DBTableName as the db/table name, and I'm manually assigning here to show the problem without having to include the looping code, which is just a distraction.

```
DECLARE @DBTableName VARCHAR(50) = '[MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable]';
DECLARE @LatestLogDT VARCHAR(25);

SET @LatestLogDT = (SELECT FORMAT(MAX([ActivityDT]), N'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm') FROM @DBTableName);
SELECT @LatestLogDT
```

However, when I run this code, I get this error message:

> Must declare the table variable "@DBNAME".

Next, I tried creating an SQL string and executing that string, but I get the same error.

I feel like I've seen this done before, but clearly I'm missing something. Probably sometime quite simple. Hoping one of you geniuses can put me on the right track.

Comment: You need dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with a dynamic Transact-SQL statement:

```
DECLARE @DBTableName VARCHAR(50) = '[MyDB].[dbo].[MyTable]';
DECLARE @LatestLogDT NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @LatestLogDT = N'SELECT FORMAT(MAX([ActivityDT]), ''yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm'') FROM' + @DBTableName;
EXEC sp_executesql @LatestLogDT
```

More info and examples on [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)